# How to come back to the same fragment after leaving application

Tags: android, lifecycle

Could anyone please help me with this problem? I have ProfileFragment with its activity and when I press on the button "Edit" in that fragment, it navigates me to editProfileActivity with its EditProfileFragment. If I roll up my app and open it with the image app again, it opens ProfileFragment and I need EditProfileFragment to be opened. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: could add some code or pictures ?

Comment: it will be great if you can elaborate more about the problem

Comment: There isn't a prebuilt solution to this specific problem, so I think your question is a bit too broad, maybe take a look into how to persist data?

Answer (score -1):

Init your ProfileFragment in oncreate maybe helpful